# リモートサーバーにgit pullする時のメモリエラー

Tags: git, sourcetree

お世話になります。
リモートサーバーにgit pullをしたいのですが、メモリエラーになり、うまくできない状況です。
いろいろ調べましたが、解決ができなく皆様からご教示いただければと思います。

### やりたいこと

リモートサーバーのgit pull

### やってみたこと

```
git config pack.windowMemory 2048m
git config pack.packSizelimit 2048m
```

### エラー

```
$ git pull
$ Username入力
$ Password入力
remote: Enumerating objects: 2189, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2189/2189), done.
remote: warning: suboptimal pack - out of memory
remote: error: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 63234233 bytes)
remote: fatal: packed object 6fffbac2e9bc4f98dc09a201b98664c77e644709 (stored in ./objects/pack/pack-82bbfdc8dc284d5dcc304fc63fe0414b97d2a281.pack) is corrupt
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header
```

何か対策等ご存知でしたら、教えていただきたいと思います。

#### 補足

以下、gitの差分の圧縮と不要なオブジェクトの削除するコマンドだと存じますが、、
`$ git gc --prune=all`
影響範囲がわからず、正直に実行が怖いのです。

①masterから切ったdevelopブランチで、修正しました。
②developブランチをpushしました。（開発環境でテストするため、masterへのマージはしませんでした。）
③developのリモートサーバーでgit pullをしようとしていて、本件のエラーが出ました。

この場合、`$ git gc --prune=all`を実行すると、masterブランチ（リモート）には影響がないでしょうか。

理解不足で、いろいろわからないことが多いですが何卒よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: 参考: 英語版での関連質問 - [Error when pulling warning: suboptimal pack - out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9040083)

Comment: @cubick コメントありがとうございました。恐れ入りますが、解決ができませんでした。よろしくお願いいたします。